# How can I handle a big json string in TYPO3

Tags: json, canvas, fabricjs, hidden-field, typo3-6.2.x

I have developed a little order extension where customers can design a business card. This extension uses a canvas in association with fabric.js.

Customers can add some text, simple forms, images and so on and the result of her customization is a json string which I bind via jquery to an hidden input to store this data in a property **image** when the form is submitted.

FLUID:

```
<f:form.hidden class="custom-image" property="image" />
```

JS:

```
$('.step3 .custom-image').val(getJsonOfCanvas());
```

HTML result:

```
<input class="custom-image" type="hidden" name="tx_example_orderform[step3data][image]" value="{&quot;objects&quot;:[{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;rect&quot;,&quot;originX&quot;:&quot;left&quot;,&quot;originY&quot;:&quot;top&quot;,&quot;left&quot;:761,&quot;top&quot;:181,&quot;width&quot;:50,&quot;height&quot;:50,&quot;fill&quot;:&quot;#68e5e7&quot;,&quot;stroke&quot;:null,&quot;strokeWidth&quot;:1,&quot;strokeDashArray&quot;:null,&quot;strokeLineCap&quot;:&quot;butt&quot;,&quot;strokeLineJoin&quot;:&quot;miter&quot;,&quot;strokeMiterLimit&quot;:10,&quot;scaleX&quot;:1,&quot;scaleY&quot;:1,&quot;angle&quot;:0,&quot;flipX&quot;:false,&quot;flipY&quot;:false,&quot;opacity&quot;:0.8,&quot;shadow&quot;:null,&quot;visible&quot;:true,&quot;clipTo&quot;:null,&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;fillRule&quot;:&quot;nonzero&quot;,&quot;globalCompositeOperation&quot;:&quot;source-over&quot;,&quot;transformMatrix&quot;:null,&quot;params&quot;:{&quot;base&quot;:1,&quot;x&quot;:761,&quot;y&quot;:181,&quot;scaleX&quot;:1,&quot;scaleY&quot;:1},&quot;rx&quot;:0,&quot;ry&quot;:0}],&quot;background&quot;:&quot;&quot;}">
```

So business card modifications increase the value of this hidden input -> a lot of modifications = big json string.

In a later order step customers can check and edit her entries and also can edit her business card again. For this reason I am using the same json string to load the canvas again:

FLUID (little bit tricky because it's inline js):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[var jsonCanvasString = ]]>
    <f:if condition="{step3data.image}">
        <f:then>
            <f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>{step3data.image}</f:format.htmlentitiesDecode>
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
            ''
        </f:else>
    </f:if>
<![CDATA[;]]>
</script>
```

JS:

```
if (typeof jsonCanvasString !== 'undefined') {
    canvas.loadFromJSON(jsonCanvasString, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
}
```

This works great when the json string is not so big, but when he is too long I get a blank page and nothing will be rendered, but if I debug my image property I can see that's the property **image** is still set:

[image]

Any suggestions?
Maybe is there a better way to store the json string and pass him from js to php or from php to js?

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: is there any way to make custom ViewHelper?

Comment: You guess a ViewHelper would be great?